# Joomla 3: How to trigger a PHP script execution following a param list change in the XML file (backend)

Tags: php, xml, joomla

Context: Joomla 3.4, XML file params changes.

I need to be able to trigger / activate a PHP script whenever a particular param field list change takes place.

This has nothing to do with the standard PHP script activations e.g. initialisation, after installation etc.

I want this PHP script to be triggered each time a change in a list setting occurs.

I have searched the various forums - but without any success.

Any help on this matter will be really appreciated.

Comment: Who is going to make the change? the developer? the user? some other script?

Comment: Where is that change happening? Inside a database table or on file level?

Answer (score 0):

In response to:

> > Who is going to make the change? the developer? the user? some other script?
> >     Where is that change happening? Inside a database table or on file level?
> >     The change is simply a param change in the admin backend of the module. (Usually such a param is under the Basic or Advanced categories. When a user in the backend makes a change to a list item, or to a field entry.

Since posting this message, it seems to me that I need to try and make use of an event 'onExtensionBeforeSave' which - as I understand it, should be triggered each time a param is saved.

I should then be able to build a plugin that can respond to that event.

I am busy trying to implement such a plugin (and supporting xml file) at present.

Alastair